# Python Logger shared with modules

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a question on how to share the Python logging device when we have other modules.

Let's say that I have `main.py` that imports file `protocol.py` and declares a logger variable.

```
import logging
from protocol import Protocol

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug("Currently in main.py")

protocol_obj_1 = Protocol(log)
protocol_obj_2 = Protocol()
```

Within `protocol.py`, let's say I wish to log additional data by sharing the same log variable.

```
class Protocol:
    def __init__(self, log_var = None):
        self.log_var = log_var

    def logData(self):
        if self.log_var is not None:
            self.log_var.debug("Currently within class Protocol")
        else:
            print("Currently no logging")
```

Is this a Pythonic approach? Or are there better ways to share the logging device with other modules?

Comment: It is a common practice to create a new logger with `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in every module.

Answer (score 3):

The most idiomatic Python way of creating a logger in a module is, as the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial):

> A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:
>
> ```
> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
> ```

But there aren't rare cases where you want different modules to log into the same logger. For instance, when it's done in a Python (distribution) package (say, distributed on PyPI). Then, if the package is "flat" then you can use `__package__` instead of `__name__` in every module.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)
```

If you have import packages in your distribution package, then you may want to provide hardcoded names in every module.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('mypackage')
```